# Class Progress Computation

Tags: average

I am making a program where I need to include the progress of an entire class based on the number of lessons they have taken versus the number of lessons available. I understand that for a single student, the formula is number of lessons taken divided by the total number of lessons times 100.

How do I compute for it in a class level?

Please take note that some students might be ahead of their classmates in answering lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could label the progress of each student as $x_1,x_2, ..., x_n$, and the number of lessons each student has taken as $y_1,y_2, ..., y_n$ with $x_i = \frac{y_i}{total number of lessons} * 100$ for student i, and n being the number of students in the class. The average would be simply $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$, where $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm sorry would you mind giving me an example? I understand the part where I need to compute for each student but I really don't understand the oter formula

Comment: The sigma notation is just simply a summation. It is the equivalent of taking the sum of all x values from i = 1 to n, then dividing the summation by n.

Comment: So is it like for example, I have 4 students whose x value is 0.4 each and 3 students whose x value is 0.2 each, so that's (2.2 / 7)*100 = 31.43%?

Comment: Yes, if you are calculating the average.

Comment: Oohh okay I get it. Thank you so much! :)